# How to turn relative route into a relative url?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a JSON API action filter that intercepts the output an inserts hypermedia URLs.

I am injecting `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider` to give me access to all of the routes.

For a known action, I have the route relative path from `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ApiExplorer.ApiDescription.RelativePath`. For example:

`/articles/{id}`

I also have the parameters for the route, in this case it's simply `{id}`.

I need to turn that relative route into a real Url. For example, for an `id` of 2, I would expect:

`/articles/2`

Is there functionality in ASP.NET 5/Core/MVC 6 that will allow me to take the parameter and the route template and create a real Url?

### Edit

Thanks for the comments, here's the results of some testing. @dealdiane is correct that [Hyprlinkr](https://github.com/ploeh/Hyprlinkr) is not compatible with DNX/aspnet core. I investigated [TypedRouting](https://github.com/ivaylokenov/AspNet.Mvc.TypedRouting) but the helpers do not use the Route templates.

I tried `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.UrlHelper` to create a link. You can inject `IUrlHelper` like any other service and use the extension methods such as:

```cs
UrlHelper helper; // Constructor injected
ApiDescription action; // I have this as a starting point

var actionDescriptor = (ControllerActionDescriptor)action.ActionDescriptor;
var actionName = actionDescriptor.Name;
var controllerName = actionDescriptor.ControllerName;
object values = new {id};

var url = helper.Action(actionName, controllerName, values);
```

Unfortunately, `url` is set to:

```
/articles?id=2
```

Which is not correct.

Comment: There's a library [Hyprlinkr](https://github.com/ploeh/Hyprlinkr) which does create urls from route values. Hope this what you are looking for.

Comment: Hyprlinkr does not work with dnx. There's [TypedRouting](https://github.com/ivaylokenov/AspNet.Mvc.TypedRouting) that you can probably use though.

Comment: What about `UrlHelper.RouteUrl`? Is the reason why you didn't/can't use `UrlHelper.RouteUrl` is because you have the route template and not the route name?